# Find the biggest file with criteria and copy it to a specific directory

Tags: linux, shell, find

I have directory `/usr/process` with many sub-directories. I want to find the biggest file named `*calculation*`. There could be millions of files to search through.

When I use the command below and sort based on size and get the biggest file and copy it to `/` it's very slow.

```
find /usr/process -name '*calculation*' | xargs -n 1 -i cp {} /usr/share/backup
```

1. How can I filter the find command to get the biggest file and copy it?
2. How can I filter the find command to get the 10 biggest file and copy it?
3. How can I filter the find command to get the smallest file and copy it?
4. How can I filter the find command to get the 10 smallest file and copy it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the file name ("calculation"), I see no interest for running `find`.

If you need to find the n (here, n=3) largest files, you can just use `du`, which stands for "disk usage" :

```
du -a /usr/bin/ 2>/dev/null | sort -n -r | head -n 3
478328  /usr/bin/
26024   /usr/bin/burpsuite
16692   /usr/bin/mariabackup
```

Of course, you need to use your own directory `/usr/process`.

Alternatively as this is  easier to pipe it, you can use `find` as follows :

```
find $HOME -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -nr | head -10
10485760 /root/.mozilla/firefox/p4r990u7.default/places.sqlite
10240000 /root/.cache/tracker/meta.db-wal
7964784 /root/.mozilla/firefox/p4r990u7.default/gmp-widevinecdm/1.4.8.903/libwidevinecdm.so
6136581 /root/.local/share/tracker/data/tracker-store.journal
6127616 /root/.mozilla/firefox/p4r990u7.default/webappsstore.sqlite
5615597 /root/.mozilla/firefox/p4r990u7.default/storage/temporary/https+++regex101.com/asmjs/module15
4728570 /root/.cache/mozilla/firefox/p4r990u7.default/safebrowsing/goog-phish-shavar.sbstore
4493312 /root/.cache/tracker/meta.db
```

Then you can pipe it as per your need.